# Currently, as a US citizen, does one require to apply for a work visa if planning to work remotely in France for up to a maximum of 30 days?

Tags: visa, working-visas, france, digital-nomads

Or would the visa-free entry granted for US Citizens be alright as long as the period of stay in France is under 90 days.

Answer (score 2):

Legally, yes, you need a work visa.

In practice, if you're working fully remotely, getting paid in the US, and have a return ticket and the funds to cover your stay in France, nobody will care.